# Ralink RT5370 wifi adapter

Tags: pi-2, wifi

Hi I can't set up Ralink RT5370 wifi adapter.
When I run **lsusb** I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

So my raspberry sees the wifi adapter.
I can't have problem with power because I use a 2A power adapter.
My file /etc/network/interfaces is edidet as:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-ssid "Your Network SSID"
   wpa-psk "Your Password"
```

Can someone help me?
Edit: Thank you to all guys, the problem was that I installed another driver, now everything is okey.(sorry)

Comment: Did you install the driver for it? --> https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi

Comment: Can you connect to the Wifi with any other client? Have you eliminated the possibility that the Wifi is bad.

Comment: Yes, I can, the wifi isn't bad

Comment: yes, I did it..

Comment: @NicuMih Could you add an answer explaining what you did to fix the problem?

Comment: I just installed the driver for ralink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "Your Network SSID" the name your router is giving to your WiFi, and enter your password instead of "Your Password".

Comment: haha, I now I just puted as an example

Comment: Just making sure :) Did you install the driver for it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found out setting up networking has changed in Jessie. See [this related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921).